# I want to update payments document if found, create a new document with the updated field, leaving the original document

Tags: node.js, mongodb, findoneandupdate

```
 const payment = await paymentsSchema.findOne({ student: s_id, guardian: g_id }, {},
          { sort: { 'createdAt': -1 } })
        console.log(payment)
        payment.balance = (payment.balance + settings.overtime_rate)
       
        // Create a new document with the updated values
        const updatedPayment =  paymentsSchema(payment.toObject());

        // Save the new document to the database
        updatedPayment.save((err) => {
          if (err) throw err;
          console.log('Payment updated successfully');
        });
```

I expect to have 2 documents after posting this update, the original and the updated document...

Comment: I get this error when i run the above code: "MongoServerError: E11000 duplicate key error collection:"

Comment: Use `findOneAndUpdate`, with `upsert: true` to do it all in one simple query, or just `update`

Comment: Hello _nimrod serok, i want to update only after I  find the document...i want to do something else if I don't find the document.

Answer (score 0):

```
const payment = await paymentsSchema.findOne({ student: s_id, guardian: g_id }, {},
      { sort: { 'createdAt': -1 } },)
    console.log(payment)
    payment.balance = (payment.balance + settings.overtime_rate)
 
    // Create a new document with the updated values
    const updatedPayment = new paymentsSchema({
      balance: payment.balance,
     . . . //other fields you may have
    });

    // Save the new document to the database
    updatedPayment.save((err) => {
      if (err) throw err;
      console.log('Payment updated successfully');
    });
```